# Win10 volume and speaker control (split audio to more devices)

Tags: audio, windows-10, volume-control

Windows 10 sound controls are limited. You can control general volume and control individual programs (not apps).

What I need is a tool that can:

- Play e.g. the radio from Microsoft Edge browser on Bluetooth speaker
- Play a video from YouTube on Chrome with the internal speaker
- Run a Skype voice call on the jack-stick head phones

All at once of course.

I am unsure that this is at all possible, but who knows? You might have the right solution for me :-)

Answer (score 4):

### Option 1:

You could use [IndieVolume](http://www.indievolume.com/). It has the features that you have mentioned in the question. Here is a screen shot.

[image]

However, the software is **not** free. You can download a trial version and check if this works for you.

Not all softwares play well with IndieVolume. So check all the softwares that you wish to use before buying(if you plan to).

---

### Option 2:

You can use [CheVolume](http://www.chevolume.com/).

Same features as IndieVolume. But not Free.

---

### Option 3:

Not the EASY way but FREE.

Install the different softwares inside different virtual machines. Virtual Machines provide you with ways to select the output for different virtual machines.

[image]

Comment: Looks close to what I'm looking for - however it only supports win xp, vista 32 and Win7 32bit - and I would of course prefer a freeware :-)

Comment: @MortenRepsdorphHusfeldt It works fine on Win10. I have installed it.

Comment: @MortenRepsdorphHusfeldt I would suggest you to download the software and give it a test drive. See how it works for you.

Comment: Looked at screen-shots from IndieVolume (discarted) and tested CheVolume (sound 'coughs' whenever changes are made) and then found a freeware alternative - answer below. Also contacted eartrumpet urging them to implement a 'pretty' solution in their win 10 volume controller.

Answer (score 3):

[**AudioRouter**](https://www.reddit.com/r/software/comments/3f3em6/is_there_a_alternative_to_chevolume/cyptuz2) is a freeware solution that is Windows 10 ready:

- [64 bit version](https://mega.nz/#!qRdgTR4R!heJ5Q40-Y1hm-0Z0nygP6Sn5ACpkheDnGThY1yqJ6mo)
- [32 bit version](https://mega.nz/#!iN13RbaJ!CkEHphI1vmO4H5H5DkND2IYThUlhxiM1D0Ng9zcC9e0)

It is simple and does the job. Hope to find a more pretty solution at some point like [EarTrumpet](https://github.com/File-New-Project/EarTrumpet/releases) for Windows 10.

Comment: Your sound card can limit the functionality - I can use Bluetooth and then either internal speaker or jack-stick-headset as my card cannot support more audio streams at once